# Regex and jquery for table filtering

Tags: jquery, filtering, tablefilter

I took some code from the internet that searches data entered in a table (contains query) but i want it to look if text appears at the beginning of the word. here is the code

```
function filter(selector, query) {
    query   =   $.trim(query); //trim white space
  query = query.replace(/ /gi, '|'); //add OR for regex

  $(selector).each(function() {
    ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(query, "i")) < 0) ? $(this).hide().removeClass('visible') : $(this).show().addClass('visible');
  });
}
```

how can i change it to look for query at beginning of the word rather than anywhere in the word
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
query = "^" + query.replace(/ /gi, '|');
```